# How do I fix this calculator UI? (Javascript from code.org) I will explain down below

Tags: javascript, calculator, calc, code.org

Ok so this is my first program that I have ever done, and this was a side project that I am trying to do in my high school cs class. So I don't really know how to explain the problem that good, so here is the link to the code, and the program. 
https://studio.code.org/projects/applab/NXVTYdQ5srab3hWcx_ihgrR6qIDuYTnXYE3NfBxxMPQ

The problem that I have right now is that once you press one of the buttons, like basic math, and then press go back, and then press it again, it created a duplicate underneath it. 
How do I fix this?

Here is the code if you don't wanna go to the link: ( and please leave any suggestions)

```
  button("basicMath","BasicMath");
  button("Der/Int","d/dx/ ∫");
  button("QF","Quadratic Formula");

var total = 0;

write("IF USING 'd/dx' or '∫', first input = base number, second = exponent");
write("IF USING EXPONENTS then first input = base number, second = exponent");

  onEvent("basicMath", "click", function() {  // OPTIONS FOR MATH 
   setScreen("BasicMath");

  textInput("num1","0"); // TEXT INPUT
  textInput("num2","0"); // TEXT INPUT
  //textInput("num3","0"); // TEXT INPUT

  button("reset", "Go Back");

  textLabel("result",''); // Result
  textLabel("writing", '');
  textLabel("ansresult", "The Answer is: ");

  setPosition("ansresult", 0, 350, 150, 70);
  setPosition("result", 130, 350, 170, 70 );
  setPosition("writing", 130, 400, 170, 70 ); 

  button("clear","clear"); // clear  Button
  button("answer", "ans");
  button("plus","+"); // +  Button
  button("subract","-"); // -  Button
  button("multiply","*"); // *  Button
  button("divide", "/"); // /  Button
  button("exponent", "^"); // Exponent Button 

   onEvent("reset","click", function() {
    setScreen("OptionsScreen");
  });
 onEvent("clear","click", function() {
   total =  0;
  setText("result", total);
    setKeyValue("answer", total, function () {
  });
});

onEvent("answer","click", function() { // Recent Answer get back

  getKeyValue("answer", function (value) {
    setText("result", value);
    });
});

  var addition = onEvent("plus","click", function() {
  if (addition === true) {
    var num1 = getNumber("num1");
    var num2 = getNumber("num2");
    //var num3 = getNumber("num3");
      total =  num1 + num2; // + num3
  setText("result", total);
  } else {
      setText("writing","Error");
  }
  setKeyValue("answer", total, function () {
  });
});

 var subract = onEvent("subract","click", function() { // Subraction
  if (subract === true) {
  var num1 = getNumber("num1");
  var num2 = getNumber("num2");
  //var num3 = getNumber("num3");
      total =  num1 - num2; // num 3
  setText("result", total);
  } else {
      setText("writing", "Error");
  }
  setKeyValue("answer", total, function () {
  });
});

var multiply = onEvent("multiply","click", function() { // Multiply
  if (multiply === true) {
   var num1 = getNumber("num1");
    var num2 = getNumber("num2");
      total =  num1 *= num2;
  setText("result", total);
  } else {
      setText("writing", "Error");
  }
  setKeyValue("answer", total, function () {
  });
});

var divide = onEvent("divide","click", function() { // Division
  if (divide === true) {
   var num1 = getNumber("num1");
    var num2 = getNumber("num2");
      total =  num1 /= num2;
  setText("result", total);
  } else {
      setText("writing", "Error");
  }
  setKeyValue("answer", total, function () {
  }); 
});

var exponent = onEvent("exponent","click", function() { // Exponents
  if (exponent === true) {
   var num1 = getNumber("num1");
    var num2 = getNumber("num2");
      total =  Math.pow(num1,num2);
  setText("result", total);
  } else {
      setText("writing","Error");
  }
  setKeyValue("answer", total, function () {
    });
  });
});

  onEvent("Der/Int", "click", function() { // d/dx / INTEGRALS
    setScreen("Deriv/Inte");

  textInput("num3","0"); // TEXT INPUT
  textInput("num4","0"); // TEXT INPUT
  button("reset1", "Go Back");

  textLabel("result1",''); // Result
  textLabel("writing1", '');
  textLabel("ansresult1", "The Answer is: ");

  setPosition("ansresult1", 0, 350, 150, 70);
  setPosition("result1", 130, 350, 170, 70 );
  setPosition("writing1", 130, 400, 170, 70 ); 

  button("clear1","clear"); // clear  Button
  button("integral", "integral"); // Integral Button
  button("derivative", "d/dx"); // Derivative Button

    onEvent("clear1","click", function() { // CLEAR BUTTON
  total =  0;
  setText("result1", total);
  setText("writing1", '');
});

  onEvent("reset1","click", function() { // GO BACK BUTTON
    setScreen("OptionsScreen");
  });

  onEvent("integral","click", function() { // Simple Integration
    var num3 = getNumber("num3");
    var num4 = getNumber("num4");
    var exponentAdd = num4 += 1;  // Reverse power rule
    var exponentDivide = num3 /= exponentAdd ; // Reverse power rule
    var result = exponentDivide; 
    setText("result1", result + 'x' + exponentAdd); // (result + 'x' + exponentAdd);
    setText("writing1","The last number is the exponent");
});

onEvent("derivative","click", function() { // SIMPLE DERIVATIVES
    var num3 = getNumber("num3");
    var num4 = getNumber("num4");
    var exponentMultiply = num4 * num3; // POWER RULE
    var exponentSubract = num4 - 1; // POWER RULE
    var result = exponentMultiply;

if (num4 === 0) {
    setText("result", "0"); // FIND THE CONSTANT IF THE EXPONENT WILL BECOME 0 OR 1
  } else if (num4 === 1) {
    setText("result1", num3);
} else {
    setText("result1", result + 'x' + exponentSubract);
    setText("writing1","The last number is the exponent");
    } 
  });
});

  onEvent("QF","click", function() { // QUADRATIC FUNCTION
  setScreen("QuadF");

  textInput("a","0"); // TEXT INPUT
  textInput("b","0"); // TEXT INPUT
  textInput("c","0"); // TEXT INPUT

  button("reset2", "Go Back");
  button("clear2","clear"); // clear  Button

  textLabel("result2",''); // Result
  textLabel("writing2", '');
  textLabel("ansresult2", "The Answer is: ");

  setPosition("ansresult2", 0, 350, 150, 70);
  setPosition("result2", 130, 350, 170, 70 );
  setPosition("writing2", 130, 400, 170, 70 ); 

  button("quadraticFormula", "Quadratic Formula");

  onEvent("clear2","click", function() {

   total =  0;
  setText("result2", total);
  setText("writing2", '');
    setKeyValue("answer", total, function () {
  });
});
 onEvent("reset2","click", function() {
    setScreen("OptionsScreen");
    });

  onEvent("quadraticFormula","click", function() { 

    var a = getNumber("a");
    var b = getNumber("b");
    var c = getNumber("c");

    var discriminate1 =  Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b,2)-4*a*c); // SQRT(B^2 - 4(a)(c)

    var discriminate2 = -b + discriminate1;
    var discriminate3 = -b - discriminate1;
    var sol1 = discriminate2/2*a;
    var sol2 = discriminate3/2*a;
      setText("result2","x = " + sol1 + " x = " +sol2);
      setText("writing2", "IF X IS 'NaN' THEN NO REAL SOLUTION!");
  });
});
```

Comment: If you would, please post all the code relevant to the question *in the question itself* - don't hide it behind a link. You shouldn't tell potential helpers who would otherwise love to help that they have to navigate offsite just to have an idea of what you're working with. If the link breaks, the question could be rendered useless to future readers. Please edit your code into the question in a [MCVE], or the question might get closed, thanks.

Comment: this question seems better suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your screen (input fields and buttons) are getting placed again and again. So, you have to see if there is a way to clear it first.

Whenever someone chooses an option from the menu, clear the screen and then build the screen again.

They might have some method like:

```
clearScreen("screen name");
```

Edit:
As there is no clearScreen option, looks like you have to create all 4 screens one by one at the start itself. OnEvent you should only change the screen. So, the screens will get created only once and stay hidden.

Comment: Its been two hours and I still have not figured it out, because the only commands I can think of is deleteElement(id); but this will delete the whole screen, so idk

Comment: Looks like you have to create all 4 screens one by one at the start itself. OnEvent you should only change the screen. So, the screens will get created only once and stay hidden.

Comment: Thank you so much, fixing it atm now :D

Comment: All fixed now, you can take a look here if you want https://studio.code.org/projects/applab/lqrduExaFDZDnJhYBkFMm1BwKNDctR-BDs3NBCNIaKE